VS Code start to print INFO messages in console
I don't know what causes my issue, and I feel stupid I can't find any solution on the internet, but suddenly my code start to print many messages in conlose while running and I don't know why:
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (%d): %s:%s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (%d): %s:%s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s

I use requests library, but I also get something simiar with PyQt:
[D:PyQt6.uic.uiparser] toplevel widget is %s
[D:PyQt6.uic.properties] setting property geometry
[D:PyQt6.uic.properties] setting property windowTitle
[D:PyQt6.uic.uiparser] push Dialog Dialog
[D:PyQt6.uic.uiparser] push QGridLayout gridLayout
[D:PyQt6.uic.properties] setting property text
[D:PyQt6.uic.uiparser] push QPushButton cancelButton
[D:PyQt6.uic.uiparser] pop widget QPushButton cancelButton

I tried to google how can I disable this messages, but I had no success.
It's really annoyng because I can't display useful information in my app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The debug messages you're seeing are caused by Python's logging system, which libraries like urllib3 and PyQt6 use to print internal details when the logging level is set to DEBUG. To stop these, you can adjust the logging level in your script by adding import logging and setting logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING), which hides everything below warnings. If you want to target specific libraries, you can use something like logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING) or logging.getLogger("PyQt6").setLevel(logging.WARNING) to quiet them down. If you’ve accidentally enabled debug logging elsewhere in your code (e.g., logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)), just change it to WARNING. And if you’re desperate to silence all logs, you can use logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL) to shut them off completely. Also, check if your environment, like Jupyter or your IDE, is forcing debug logs, as they sometimes do. This should clean up your console and make it easier to focus on your app’s output.

Thanks, I used logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING) to clear all messages at once
